# Using AWK to treat files

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I want to create a batch file with awk, grep or sed that keeps all lines beginning with 'INSERT' and deletes the other lines.

After this, I want to replace a string "change)" by "servicechange)" when the 3rd word in the treated line is "donextsit".

Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: Since we don't know your time zone, there is a strong temptation to assume you are in Hawaii, and not provide the answer until 3:58 HST.  SO isn't primarily a homework service.  And while you normally get rapid answers, trying to hold SO to your deadline is not reasonable - especially when it isn't clear when the deadline actually is.

Comment: Thx to edgar.holleis and ghostdog74.  
It seems good ideas but i have some problems again. :(  
I want to put the result in a file. How to do this? I think it's the "print" command that may be replaced by something else.
Who can help me?

Comment: @Kev: I agree that the time request was not appropriate, but now it isn't clear what the first comment is referring to.  What to do?  The information in the comment is generally applicable.  Maybe it doesn't need to be said here.

Comment: @jonathon - probably delete the comment. Doesn't really add value and judging by user profile, he's long gone. I'd have edited post and left a reason-comment there about "Help! I need this NOW" instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/INSERT/{ 
    if ($3=="donextsit"){
       gsub("change","servicechange");
       print
    }
}' file
```

since this is homework, something is still not working..you should find out for yourself

Comment: could also avoid the if statement: `awk '/^INSERT/ && $3 == "donextsit" { gsub(); print}' file`

Comment: I interpret his qns differently. My guess is he wants to print the INSERT statements that doesn't have "donextsit" as well. NB: my solution is not complete on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
    /^INSERT/ ! d;
    /^ *[^ ]\+ *[^ ]\+ *donextsit / s/change)/servicechange)/g;
' -i file
```

Edit: Incorporated Jonathan Leffler's suggestions.

Comment: Easier: `sed '/^INSERT/!d; ...' ...` which saves on labels and branches.